# Using variables in pivot data source

Tags: vba

I would like to replace:

`C:\Users\test_h\Downloads\New folder\[Book1.xlsm]` and `Sheet1` with a variable from the code below:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _

 PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _

 "C:\Users\test_h\Downloads\New folder\[Book1.xlsm]Sheet1!R1C1:R30C14", Version _
 :=xlPivotTableVersion14)
```

---

I've tried, but cannot get it to work:

```
Sub test(sht As String, path_name As String)

   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _

   PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _

   path_name & sht & !R1C1:R30C14", Version _

   :=xlPivotTableVersion14)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having syntax issues: missing quotation and breaking lines within object reference. These errors are caught by the compiler before any run of the code.  Also, use the `Cells()` reference instead of `R1C1` address reference. Plus, you are combining a string reference to a workbook and worksheet with a Range Address.

Therefore, consider using declared variables (and be sure to uninitialize):

```
Dim wkb As Workbook, wks As Worksheet
Dim SourceRng As Range
Dim NewCache As PivotCache

Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\test_h\Downloads\New folder\Book1.xlsm")
Set wks = wkb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set SourceRng = wks.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(30, 14))
Set NewCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                     SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                     SourceData:=SourceRng, _
                     Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache NewCache

Set wkb = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
Set SourceRng = Nothing
Set NewCache = Nothing
```

Usually for readability it helps to break arguments into different lines. Of course this is just a personal preference.